# Creating Sets/Lists

Tags: java, list, collections, set

Write a public class method makeTestSet() which takes no argument, that creates and returns an empty unsorted set whose elements are declared to be of type EOHoverFrog.

```
public static int makeTestSet() {
Set<EOHoverFrog> set = new set<EOHoverFrog>();
}
```

Write a public class method makeTestList() which takes no arguments, that creates an returns an empty list whose elements are declared to be of type EOHoverFrog.

```
public static int makeTestList() {
Set<EOHoverFrog> list = new list<EOHoverFrog>();
}
```

Write a public class method makeTestSortedSet() which takes no argument, and creates and returns an empty sorted set whose elements are declared to be of type EOHoverFrog.

```
public static int makeTestSortedSet() {
Set<EOHoverFrog> set = new set<EOHoverFrog>();
}
```

Have I done this correctly?

Comment: There are not classes ''set'' and ''list''. You propably mean HashSet, ArrayList and SortedSet.

Comment: @Excel20...SortedSet is an interface.

Comment: first of all your methods must create and ***return*** given things. your code doesn't retun anything at all (and even it has `int` as type of returning value isntead of void).

Comment: I really believe you should read a tutorial first. There are excellent books and tutorials on the internet on how to start with Java.

Answer (score 4):

This code contains errors that would be picked up by trying to compile the code with a Java compiler: the compiler will not accept these programs.

The compile errors should tell you a number of things are wrong with your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Ill help you with one, and you can figure out the others

> Write a public class method makeTestList() which takes no arguments,
>   that creates an returns an empty list whose elements are declared to
>   be of type EOHoverFrog.

```
public static int makeTestList() {
Set<EOHoverFrog> list = new list<EOHoverFrog>();
}
```

Ok, the directions say that you need a method with:

1) no arguments...
2) return an empty List with elements of type EOHoverFrog

Look at your code.

What type did you declare your `makeTestList` method to return?  `int`.  What's it supposed to return?

What is the declared type of what you are creating?  `Set`  Whats it supposed to be?

What are you returning?  I dont see a return statement.

The one statement in your method, what is it doing? Declaring a Set with the name list, and assigning a new list to it.  Does that really make sense to you?

Keep in mind that  `Set` and `List` are interfaces, and you can only create implementations. like `Hashset` and `ArrayList`.

As others have mentioned, this code probably wont even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to second task seems wrong (list is of type Set)

Same goes for answer to third task (you need an empty **sortedSet**)